# CI 3.1.0 base url creating issue while opening website with www.domainname.com and domainname.com

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is how I define my base URL:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://royalarcdevelopments.ca';
```

Now this is a live link you can test it yourself:

what happens is if i open this url using the path `http://royalarcdevelopments.ca` , `royalarcdevelopments.ca` it loads fine for both!

But when I load it using the URL `www.royalarcdevelopments.ca` I receive this error:

```
(index):1 Access to Font at 'http://royalarcdevelopments.ca/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf' from origin 'http://www.royalarcdevelopments.ca' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.royalarcdevelopments.ca' is therefore not allowed access.
```

now I know that my base URL is not using `www` so it throws the error to me!

My question is, how can we modify `base URL` so that it accepts a request from every path type!

Comment: You're supposed to put a trailing slash on your base_url.

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://royalarcdevelopments.ca/'; like this?

Comment: Like: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://royalarcdevelopments.ca/';` This is not your answer, but you should correct it anyway.

Comment: nops! still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the www and non-www versions of the same domain are two different fully qualified domains.

Due to security reasons, some resources (like fonts in your particular case) violate the CORS policy - it results in the error you are receiving.

One solution would be to modify your web server's config so it allows the delivery of font files for cross origin requests.

A better solution would be (also from a SEO point of view) to redirect one of the domains to the other one, so you have only one "official" domain for your website. This can also be done from your web server's config or even from Codeigniter code, for example via some pre_controller hook. This way, when a visitor tries to access your secondary domain (let's say the www version in your particular case), it gets redirected to your primary domain (the non-www) and there is no more trouble with CORS.

Redirect as early as you can:

- First, if you have access to the web server's configuration, implement redirection there;
- Second, if you are using Apache as the web server, implement redirection in a `.htaccess` file;
- If none of the above options are available for you, then do it from your application code.

Comment: i was thinking about this solution myself! but how do i redirect www versions to http version using php code?